# How to Create Relationship in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, foreign-keys

As the following screenshot demonstrates, I am trying to create a relationship between NOTES.PARENT_ID and FILES.ID.  How can I accomplish this?  I have looked at many references such as http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightwinphone/thread/0043364b-ba03-482c-9fd5-12ae2c7692c3/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384511.aspx but haven't been able to figure this out.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: See my answer, you have the parent and child classes the wrong way round in your screenshot.

Comment: I see, now (that should have been obvious).  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Linq to SQL designer, you can right click in the designer and click Add > Association.

You would then choose the fields from each table to be involved in the relationship.

In your case, parent class would be FILE and child class would be NOTE.

Adding the relationship this way only applies the relationship to the Linq to SQL context.  To add the relationship in the database itself, you will have to use the table designer, which is accessible by connecting to the server in visual studio's server explorer.

If the relationship was first added to the database, the Linq to SQL designer would pick up on this and automatically add the relationship.

Comment: **Thank you, this gets me close, but, please see my edit.**  Both FILES.ID and NOTES.PARENT_ID are `uniqueidentifier`s.  Why won't it let me create the association?

Comment: You have your parent and child classes the wrong way round in the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked.  I would also like to learn how to code this manually in the `designer.cs`.  I looked at the code after I saved the `.dbml` file but it doesn't look like there is any relation code.  Do you know what I am asking?

Comment: Don't ever make manual changes to the designer, this is an auto generated code file and any changes that you make will be overwritten next time the Linq to SQL code generator runs.  I strongly recommend that you add the relationship to the database before creating the Linq to SQL design.

Comment: So, you don't advise working directly with the designer (clicking "add relationship, etc.)?

Comment: Using the graphical designer interface is correct.  You said you would like to code the relationship manually in the designer.cs, this shouldn't be done because this code is auto generated.

Comment: That is what I was trying to clarify.  That makes sense.  Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171915.aspx

**You have to create the primary keys of both tables first!**

- Creating the Relationship Between the Tables

  The relationship is created between the common column from each table — in this case, the CustomerID column.
  To configure a new relationship between the Customers and Orders tables:

  Drag a Relation object from the DataSet tab of the Toolbox onto the Orders table.

  The Relation dialog box opens.

  In the Parent Table box, select Customers.

  In the Child Table box, select Orders.

  In the Columns box, set Key Columns to CustomerID.

  In the Columns box, set Foreign Key Columns to CustomerID.

  Click OK to create the relationship; a relation line appears on the designer between the two tables.

  On the Data menu, choose Show Relation Labels.

Comment: I get stuck on `Drag a Relation object`.  I have no Relation object in my Toolbox on the designer.  I just have Pointer, Association, Class and Inheritance.  Association will not drag over to my tables...

Comment: Both tables have the PK symbol on them, as you can see, so (yes) I believe they have primary keys.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I found the answer above (Oliver).

Answer (score 1):

If at all possible, I would define this relationship in the database.

By creating a foreign key relationship between the two tables in your database:

***(a)*** The association you ask for in your question would be added automatically

and

***(b)*** The database will actually enforce that all `NOTE` rows, must be associated with an existing `FILE`

Comment: This is a good point, but I wanted to learn how to do it in the designer and I would also like to learn how to code it into the `designer.cs`.